# Ajax data sending format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Is my Ajax format something wrong? 
I am trying to send a simple digit 1/0 data to a tomcat server, using ajax
but getting no response. The whole view is at a standstill.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: "http://192.168.200.163:8080/ControllerWebServer/mainCTRL.jsp", 
            data: “fan=” + fan,
            success: function(fan){
                alert(fan);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Ajax Error.");
            }
        });
```

If I make this ajax block as a comment, other functions (which is not displayed here) work just well. I tried GET AND POST, and just the same: don't work.

please help... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
data: “fan=” + fan,
```

to

```
data: {fan: fan},
```

This is how data should be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i have low reputation so i couldnt make comment.

when you using `data: {fan: fan},` you need to specify the `dataType:'json'` in your ajax

Comment: and make it post not get